# Relaunch app from code inside app iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, in-app-purchase

I need to relaunch my app when the user completes an in app purchase. Is this possible without any user action.

What I really need is to avoid the navigation controller that is associated with the subscribe link in a table view controller.

Once a user subscribes I can get from the subscribe table view to the main app but the navigation controller tags along covering up all of my navigation items in all of the views in the main app.

Comment: Why do you want to relaunch? Why cant you update your data layer and UI layers? I dont think Apple will allow relaunch from app in any case.

Comment: There is noway Apple will allow it, since the iOS SDK has not method other then crashing an app to exit an app.

Comment: @adev, can you say me how to update app language, I am also new on swift and don't know how to implement that problem

Comment: What do you mean by app language?  You can update the data and UI in your app anytime. That depends on the code you wrote. We cant help without seeing the complete project code.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to relaunch the app from the springboard. You might just want to refresh the current view. Apple is pretty restrictive. You can also tell the user to force quit the app, but I don't think that is great UX. Good luck! Hope this answers your question.

Cheers,
Theo

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a navigationContoller it will not actually relaunch your app but will update all UI to show as app is relaunched just connect a navigation controller on first screen of your application and don't make navigationConroller as initial Controller

```
let rootviewcontroller: UIWindow = ((UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window)!)!
        rootviewcontroller.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rootnav")
        let mainwindow = (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!)!
        mainwindow.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.6477, saturation: 0.6314, brightness: 0.6077, alpha: 0.8)
        UIView.transition(with: mainwindow, duration: 0.55001, options: transition, animations: { () -> Void in
        }) { (finished) -> Void in

        }
```

Comment: A navigation controller covers up all of my navigation items I use in my app in all of my screens. In fact if I could code the subscribe table view to work without a navigation controller, everything work..

Comment: self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true used this ? in did load and willAppear